# jQuery function .on works in 1.8.3 but not in 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that works with jQuery 1.8.3 but when I upgrade to 1.9.1 it's not working anymore, but there's no change in documentation. Does somebody know how to fix this?

```
$(document).on("hover", "#cart-left", function(){
    $("#cart").addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/michalcerny/R9HZp/

Thanks for support!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 1.9.1 you should use `mouseover`

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "#cart-left", function(){
    $("#cart").addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**The status of the `hover` shorthand**

As of jQuery 1.8 the `hover` shorthand has been *deprecated*. See the [jQuery `on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Deprecated as of jQuery 1.8: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave"

As of jQuery 1.9, the `hover` shorthand is *unsupported*. See the [jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event)

**Alternative**

In your case, it means you should use the `mouseenter` event. For example:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#cart-left", function(){
     $("#cart").addClass('active');
});
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R9HZp/2/)**

**Making better usage of `on()`**

It's also worth noting that unless the selector passed to `on()` refers to elements that are added to the DOM dynamically (i.e. after page load), there's no need to *delegate* the handler to the `document`. Instead, in this case you can probably *bind* the handler function directly to the element like so:

```
$("#cart-left").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $("#cart").addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not on the "on" function, but rather the "hover" pseudo-event that has been deprecated (and removed) in 1.9.1: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event