# adding value to title attribute in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am trying to set title dynamically to the native drop-down to show tool-tip, but when I am trying to set title on hover I can't select any value from drop down options. That drop down is getting closed.

```
$(container).on("hover","select", function (e) {
  $(this).attr("title",$(this).val());
});
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: please add a fiddle , also what is container ?

Comment: container is just a parent <div> I am rendering DOM by soy template so I have to do event delegation.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772287/does-jquery-have-a-handleout-for-delegatehover

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this issue was occuring only in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.on("hover")` event was removed in [jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes).

You could try this:

```
$(container).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).val());
  }, function() {
    $(this).attr("title", "");
  }
);
```

Comment: Your suggestion might work, but I was talking about your statement that $.on() is incorrect.

Comment: i mean use "hover" in such way `$(container).on('hover', function(){})` It isn't work

Comment: Have you even tried? It does work, hence your statement is false.

Comment: Appologies. It seems you are partly correct. The "hover" event has been deprecated in jQuery since 1.9. Older versions work: http://jsfiddle.net/zz9kT/2/ Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830064/jquery-function-on-works-in-1-8-3-but-not-in-1-9-1

Comment: In our project we are using jquery 1.8.3 so hover works like that. But my question was why I was unable to select value from drop down only when I am using title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event - not sure whether some other script is closing the dropdown

```
$('body').on("mouseenter", "select", function (e) {
    $(this).attr("title", this.value);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wtg7N/)

Comment: I know it is working with mouse enter.This problem is occuring mouse leave and hover is combination of two it is not working. But I just want to know the reason why only "title" attribute causing this problem.

Comment: @user3090654 which is the `hover` event... can you edit the fiddle to recreate the problem