# Does JS work with include files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

I am using an include file to add the navigation bar to all of my pages. inside the inc file i have my JS css and html table, everything is working except for the js function that is supposed to show the hidden sub links. its been forever since ive coded js so i followed a tutorial and i can not figure out why this isnt working. here is my code::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(200);
        });
    });
</script>


<style type="text/css">

#nav{
    background-color: #282828;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

}

ul{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;


}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkgray;
    padding: 0 10px;

}

ul li li{
    background-color: #282828;
    display: none;
}

ul li ul li{
    width: 100%;

}


ul li:hover{
    background-color: red;
}

</style>


<div id="nav" class="click-nav">

    <ul class="ul">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Command Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Wiki</a></li> <br>
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li> <br>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li> <br>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery function .on works in 1.8.3 but not in 1.9.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830064/jquery-function-on-works-in-1-8-3-but-not-in-1-9-1) <-- answers the question, `.hover()` is/was a shorthand for `.on( 'hover' )`

Comment: @Juhana - No, the [`.hover()` *method*](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is still supported. It's only passing the *string* `'hover'` to `.on()` that doesn't work anymore. So this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's dev console? Your code (after the edit to remove the quotes from around `document`) works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/3o64uhuh/

Comment: thanks, your comment helped . it ended up being a bad reference to jquery file.  i had was traveling from root directory instead of going back one folder.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

was an invalid reference to my jquery file. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I've just tried it with jQuery 12.2 and 11.1, which seems to work: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2cq1badz/

```
 $('li').hover(function () {
    console.log($(this).find('ul>li'));
    $(this).find('ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(200);
});
```

I've also checked you're correctly selecting the drop-down items, so that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: So your answer is "this isn't a problem"? Except obviously it *is* a problem for the OP...

Comment: I thought it might be an issue related to refreshing the browser, or something unrelated to the code itself.